# How to implement EmojiTextView in fragment?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, fragment, emoji

I have an emoji in one of my data in cloud firestore. How do I can make the value readable in my fragment,recycleview? When adding old emoji such as , it shows in my recycler view but when ading new emoji such as "". Is it because of my android keyboard or language didn't update? I hope anyone can solve my problem.

ForumAdapter.java

```
public ForumHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        android.view.View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardviewforumtitle,parent,false);
        EmojiCompat.init(new BundledEmojiCompatConfig(v.getContext()));
        return new ForumHolder(v);

    }
    class ForumHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        EmojiTextView textViewTitle;
        EmojiTextView textViewDescription;
        EmojiTextView timeStamp;
        /*
        TextView textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewDescription;
        TextView timeStamp;*/
        public ForumHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            timeStamp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimestamp);

            textViewTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    // NO_POSITION to prevent app crash when click -1 index
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener !=null ){
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position),position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Because I got this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
```

cardviewforumtitle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="name"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="description"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTimestamp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="timestamp"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilePic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the content of R.layout.cardviewforumtitle

Comment: @user840754 i already edit my question. do i need to update my keyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `TextViews` with

```
<androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
   ..../>
```

in the layout.

Comment: i got this error `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView`

Comment: Do you get something like         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EmojiCompat is not initialized. Please call EmojiCompat.init() first in the eror message. Is the         EmojiCompat.init(config)
called in your Application class?

Comment: Problem solved after i add EmojiCompat.init(config) in my MainActivity